# Adjusting WPF Grid ColumnDefinition widths based on with of the whole grid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a grid that looks like this:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--  Name  -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        <!--  Separator  -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>

        <!--  Session Id  -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width=".5*"  MaxWidth="240" />
        <!--  Separator  -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />

        <!--  Bag  -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=CurrentBagNumber,
                                          Path=Width}" />
        <!--  Bag Status  -->
        <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding ElementName=BagStatusText,
                                          Path=Width}" />

        <!--  Several more static width columns  -->        
        .....
```

This has the session Id Column half as big as the Name column.  But what is really want is to have session ID be .1 as big as name when the grid is around 1024 px in width.  And have the session ID be .9 the size of name when the grid is around 2000 px in width.  And to have a smooth ajustment between those two as it is resized.

Kind of like a gradient percentage.

**So, to recap, SessionId is much smaller than Name when the grid is small, but is about the same size as Name when the grid is large.  Is this possible in WPF?**

Answer (score 0):

With the WPF grid out of the box, no, what you are asking is not possible.

However, you could use an attached behavior to customize the column width, dynamically changing the Width parameter of the ColumnDefinition depending on the width of the screen.

```
<ColumnDefinition ns:MyBehavior.SmallWidth="0.1*" 
     ns:MyBehavior.LargeWidth="0.5*" 
     ns:MyBehavior.Threshold="1024" 
     ns:MyBehavior.CurrentWidth="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}}" />
```

ns = your behavior namespace

CurrentWidth is the binding to the width of your current window / control

In the implementation for MyBehavior, you'd have 4 attached dependency properties that would manually set the ColumnDefinition Width property based on the SmallWidth/LargeWidth/Threshhold/CurrentWidth

[See here for more information on Attached Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms749011%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)